# how to avoid objcopy blowing up the file?

Tags: elf, objcopy

I use `objcopy` to extract/replace some section is an ELF file on a windows system.

```
>objcopy.exe -V
GNU objcopy 2.17.50 20060824
Copyright 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License.  This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

This works in general.

But my elf file contains debug information which I need to remove before delivery to decrese the filesize.

I found tht option `-g` or `--strip-debug` should do what I want:

```
>"objcopy.exe" --strip-debug -I elf32-big -O elf32-big with-debug.elf without-debug.elf
```

But it fails miserably. instead of making the file smaller it blows up the file size from ~20MB to 3GB before failing with:

```
objcopy.exe: without-debug.elf: File truncated
objcopy.exe: without-debug.elf: No space left on device
```

how do I corectly remove debug information from ELF using objcopy?

---

Don't know if this is important but objcopy issues some warnings for most ot the sections in the ELF like this:

```
BFD: without-debug.elf: warning: allocated section `.sdata' not in segment
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug in binutils.

You are using 10 year old version, and not an official release but a snapshot taken at random time.

I would try current release of binutils (version 2.28) first -- there is a chance whatever bug you are hitting has already been fixed. And if it hasn't, you can report it in binutils [bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/).

Comment: my problem is that I'm bound to that version. the newer versions have a different behavior at another feature which makes trouble...